# clojure jdbc: how to insert into a table with a specific schema?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

In the url for jdbc clojure http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/home.html

It gives the following example to insert into a table

```
(jdbc/insert! db-spec :table {:col1 42 :col2 "123"}) ;; Create
```

But for database like postgresql, it could have a non-public schema, suppose I have created a schema like template, then how to insert into template.mytable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify the table name as `:template.mytable`, or as the string `"template.mytable"`.