# Clojure Selecting records from a table and inserting those records into another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, clojure

I am trying to insert data into one database from a different database. I have the select query working but I haven't been able to take the select query and insert it into a different database and or table.

```
(jdbc/query db ["select * from employees
                    where employee_id = 1927"]
                {:as-arrays? true})
```

Now, how do I now insert the above data into another table dynamically?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29330407/1531971

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your `employees` table looks like this:

```
create table employees (
    employee_id integer,
    name        text,
    primary key (employee_id)
);
insert into employees (employee_id, name) values (123, 'taylor');
```

I wouldn't use `:as-arrays? true` for the query, because the row maps `query` returns *by default* are easier to work with.

```
(jdbc/query db ["select * from employees where employee_id = ?" 123])
;; notice query parameterization; important! ----------------^  ^
=> ({:employee_id 123, :name "taylor"})
```

And we can `def` that for use later, taking the `first` result assuming `employee_id` is unique, so `my-employee` will be a single map (or nil if not found):

```
(def my-employee
  (first (jdbc/query db ["select * from employees where employee_id = ?" 123]))
```

Now let's assume your other table you want to insert into looks like this:

```
create table employees_too (
    employee_id integer,
    name        text,
    phone       text, -- just a new column
    primary key (employee_id)
);
```

Then you could insert that employee row like this:

```
(db/insert! conn "employees_too"
            (assoc my-employee
                   :phone (str (rand-int 9999999999))))
=> ({:employee_id 123, :name "taylor", :phone "250505207"})
```

And the inserted row map(s) are returned (at least when using PostgreSQL).

You may want to create reusable functions for these operations:

```
(defn get-employee [id]
  (first (db/query conn ["select * from employees where employee_id = ?" id])))
(defn employee->employee-too [employee]
  (assoc employee :phone (str (rand-int 99999))))
(defn insert-employee-too [employee-too]
  (db/insert! conn "employees_too" employee-too))
```

A function to get an employee by ID, a function to transform an employee row/map into the *other* `employees_too` table's schema, and a function to insert a row/map into that table. You can tie them all together like this:

```
(-> (get-employee 123)
    (employee->employee-too)
    (insert-employee-too))
=> ({:employee_id 123, :name "taylor", :phone "8147"})
```

Comment: `(-> 123 get-employee employee->employee-too insert-employee-too)`

Answer (score -1):

Please see

- [the Clojure Cookbook DB chapter](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/06_databases/6-00_introduction.asciidoc)
- [clojure-doc.org SQL page](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html)